# Would I need to replace this whole tub if I were to tile the surround?

Tags: tiling

I noticed that the tub and surround look like they go together. Does that mean I have to replace both of them if I wanted to do a tiled surround?

[image: tub surround]

Comment: The tub and surround look like a typical one piece unit in which case the answer is yes. However, it's hard to tell from the pic if it is one piece. It appears there may be a seam just above the back of the tub in which case you may be able to pull out the surround and replace it with tile.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not (have to replace the tub, that is), though you won't know for sure until you remove the surround. The surround probably just lays over top of the flange on the tub, though it may be attached to the tub.  One you have the surround removed, you can re-evaluate.  You may find that you have to build the wall out a bit to match the tub flange, and provide a water proof backer (cement board) in order to mount the tiles properly.

Here's typical installation.  Picture is from FamilyHandyman.com

[image]